# mysql MATCH query white-space not considered correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a mysql MATCH query with regex matching using FULL TEXT index. The matching is done Ok. as long as I don't have a white-space inside my matching pattern. For example This matches good:
`SELECT * , 
MATCH (
name
)
AGAINST (
'Lady*'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
) AS SCORE`

But this doesn't:
`SELECT * , 
MATCH (
name
)
AGAINST (
'Lady G*'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
) AS SCORE`

It just matches as if I wrote
`SELECT * , 
MATCH (
name
)
AGAINST (
'G*'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
) AS SCORE`

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE instead of BOOLEAN.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE articles (
    ->  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    -> title VARCHAR(200),
    -> body TEXT,
    -> FULLTEXT (title,body)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
    -> ('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
    -> ('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
    ->  ('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles
    -> WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    -> AGAINST ('stands for' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
| id | title          | body                         |
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
|  1 | MySQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ... |
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('stands fo*' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
| id | title          | body                         |
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
|  1 | MySQL Tutorial | DBMS stands for DataBase ... |
+----+----------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I replaced "IN BOOLEAN MODE" with "IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE" and I'm getting syntax error. How can that be?